# NoMachine 3.5 Client Can't Connect to 4.0 Server?

Tags: centos6, nomachine-nx

I read that 3.5 client should be able to connect to 4.0 server.

However, when I tried to connect, I got this log:
NX> 203 NXSSH running with pid: 4468
NX> 285 Enabling check on switch command
NX> 285 Enabling skip of SSH config files
NX> 285 Setting the preferred NX options
NX> 200 Connected to address: x.y.z on port: 42228
NX> 202 Authenticating user: nx
NX> 208 Using auth method: publickey
NX> 204 Authentication failed.

Then, I looked at:
https://www.nomachine.com/DT12I00037#3.1

It seems like 4.0 needs some setup for the authentication part.  With 3.5, installing the rpm is the only step.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client 3.5.0 connects to a server by SSH protocol and NoMachine login (public key authentication), while NoMachine 4 (free) supports only connections by NX protocol.

To be able to connect with NX client 3.5.0, you need to install any of the NoMachine Terminal Server or Enterprise products v. 4 that supports SSH connections.

More about this is available here: https://www.nomachine.com/AR04H00561

Alternatively, install NoMachine client (version 4) on the computer you are connecting from and use the NX protocol to connect.